# Mail screen scrolls down to the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, email

I am invoking a mail intent in

```
    ImageButton mail=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mailgps);
    mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.mail);
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String emailto[]={"myemail"};
            String subject="GPS User Report";
            String body="Welcome to Samarth Reporting service.Did you see an untracked Dustbin\n.A dustbin not at the right place??\nWant to suggest placement of a dustbin here.\nGo ahead we are all ears.\n.Your present location is\n Latitude: ";
            body=body +  "28.67890" + " and Longitudes: " + "79.78965";
            body=body + "\n\nTell us more.";
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailto);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body);

            startActivity(emailIntent);  



        }
    });
```

and getting the screen like this which ignores the EXTRA_EMAIL attribute as well as EXTRA_SUBJECT and then the body appears at the very bottom.How can I rectify this.??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a pretty stupid thing.
As earlier I was using another AVD I had the email client setup so it worked nicely.But on the new AVD I overlooked that.So "first" setup the email client then go for invoking intent.
Nonetheless the system should have a better way of handling such situations rather than showing a weird blank screen.